# multiple copies of code in java

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee

I have a website having multiple users accessing the website at the same time.
In my website i have a method used to generate the random number that is further used in transactions.This random number is generated by calling a procedure written in MYSQL.

My procedure  is as below
    DELIMITER $$

```
BEGIN
declare trc_id INT;

SELECT  distinct column1 into trc_id FROM table1 where column2=match_name and         status='A';

set abc=trc_id+1;

update table1 set column1=str_id where column2=match_name  and column1=trc_id;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Now what happen is when two users calls the procedure at the same time then they both get the same number ,which causes inconsistency.

I have made the method synchronized but still users are getting the same number when called the procedure at same time.

and one more thing that my code is present on two server, they both are active at the same time but the procedure is only one.

Comment: Could you explain more about the code being present on multiple servers? Is the cluster of servers expected to deliver unique numbers from the one range, or does each server have its own number range?

Comment: hi bohemian,

actually the code is present on two server and when the user visits the website it can either go to server A or Server B.

and when two users visits the website at same time on server A and Server B and incidentally calls the procedure at the same time then issue arises.

Comment: What is the purpose of `set abc=trc_id+1;`? `abc is not used anywhere. Can you please check your code to make sure it's correct. A little formatting wouldn't be unwarranted either.